# testing a client server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I wrote a server that listens for client messages, it's a variation of http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html.  I wrote them both in eclipse as java classes in the same project.  To test it I have a client class with a main that starts the server and then sends messages to it.  When I run it the program just hangs at serverSocket.accept(); according to the javadoc for ServerSocket accept is not asynchronous?  That would explain the hanging, but then how does the tutorial code work then?

UPDATE - here is my working code:
Here is the working code:

MyServer.java

```
/*imports neglected for brevity */
public class MyServer {
public static final String hostname = "localhost";
public static final int portNum = 4444;

ServerSocket serverSocket;
BufferedReader serverReader;

File serverLog;
FileWriter fw;
BufferedWriter serverWriter;

Socket clientSocket;

public static void main(String[] args) {
MyServer server = new MyServer(portNum);
    // start the server so it can listen to client messages
    server.start();


}


public MyServer(int portNum) {

    try {
        // endpt for server side, used to listen for client socket
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNum);

        /* have server socket listen for connection, return client socket.
         * serverSocket can now talk to clientSocket
         */
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        // server writes messages to this log
        serverLog = new File("ServerLog.txt");
        if(!serverLog.exists())
            serverLog.createNewFile();
        fw = new FileWriter(serverLog.getAbsoluteFile());
        serverWriter = serverWriter = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        /* server reads from this stream that is populated by the client's
         * OUTPUT stream/client socket's INPUT stream
         */
        serverReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())
                                              );
    }    
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void start() {
    String clientMsg;
    try {
        while((clientMsg = serverReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if(clientMsg.startsWith("exit")) {
                break;
            }
            serverWriter.append(clientMsg);
        }
        serverWriter.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

MyClient.java
        public class MyClient {
        public static final String hostname = "localhost";
        public static final int portNum = 4444;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String msg = "message 1";
    try {
        // server is listening on http://localhost:4444
        Socket serversSocket = new Socket(hostname, portNum);
        PrintWriter clientOut = new     PrintWriter(serversSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

        // send first message
        clientOut.println(msg);

        msg = "message 2";
        // send second message
        clientOut.println(msg);

        msg = "exit";
        // this will stop the server
        clientOut.println(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial assumes you are not running them in the same program.  If you must run them in the same program, then start your server in a separate thread.

Comment: Are you saying I should run them in separate projects?  I just made the client into a project and the server in another project.  I run my client program and it still blocks on the accept() method.  I actually dont understand how this program could run without being multithreaded or on separate computers.

Comment: You don't need separate computers, just separate applications. Both your projects should have a "main" method. The server should create the server, and the client should connect to it. Right now, you're starting the server in your client code, which basically makes that a server instead. You need to move that code to "main" in MyServer.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted my working code in the original question for others.

Answer (score 1):

If you go through the tutorial it creates two applications one with client one with server.

You cannot create a variation like this as, when you call the constructor, your whole application blocks in `clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();`.

If you insist on creating a single application for whatever reason, you can do multithreading. But I do not see any reason why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an android phone you can test this with the app TCP socket
make sure you PortForward the port the server is listening to.
some isp also block ports so make sure with your isp that all ports are open 
trust me broke my head on this one :)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

also make sure your server has the public ip and not local ip

if you test this localy then the code above is fine if not you will need to add

```
bind(SocketAddress endpoint)
/*Binds the ServerSocket to a specific address (IP address and port number).*/
```

you can find your ip by typeing in google: whats my ip